# Error code 282 when viewing a report in Reporting Services in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I have SharePoint 2007 with Reporting Services in SharePoint integrated mode installed in a development environment.

When I try to open a report (it doesn't matter which of the reports that are installed) from SharePoints web interface I always receives this error:

> Error
>
> Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error. (rsSharePointError)

When I go to the SharePoint error log I get a little bit more detailed error message:

> ReportingServicesService.exe (0x085C) 0x0F50 Windows SharePoint
>   Services Database                                       6f8g
>   Unexpected Unexpected query execution failure, error code 282.
>   Additional error information from SQL Server is included below. "The
>   'proc_GetTpWebMetaDataAndListMetaData' procedure attempted to return a
>   status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned
>   instead." Query text (if available): "{?=call
>   proc_GetTpWebMetaDataAndListMetaData(?,'D3CE4DEA-E1BA-4019-87EF-08B4C9BEECBE',?,NULL,1,?,?,6187)}"

What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update September/23/2014**

The image below shows a screenshot when the error occurs in SharePoint:

[image: Error in sharepoint]

The image below shows a screenshot from the 'Central Administration Settings' in SharePoint for the 'Reporting Services Integration'. When I go to the url for "Report Server Web Service URL" the web browser only shows a directory list. Is that right?

[image: Central administration settings in SharePoint]

The version number of Reporting Services and Sharepoint is:

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.0.1600.22

SharePoint version 12.0.0.6421

Comment: Your build numbers are out-of-date - both products have SP3 available. I would install those then retest.

Answer (score 1):

Your build numbers are out-of-date - both products have SP3 available. I would install those then retest.

Comment: It works in the production environment that uses the same versions, the problem only occurs in the development environment. So it has nothing to do with the versions. :(

Comment: You asked this question over a month ago, and you still havent resolved it, so how can you be sure?  Why would you keep testing, using software which has known bugs, that can be easily rectified by applying a service pack?